# Extend VMware persistent volume in Kubernetes

Tags: storage, kubernetes, vmware-vsphere

How to extend VMware persistent volume (PV/PVC) with Kubernetes's VMwware in-tree driver ?

(using Rancher 2.5 with VMware/vSphere cloud provider, and Kubernetes 1.18)

I created a storageclass with the following UI options: *Provider: VMWare vSphere Volume* and **Allow Volume Expansion : Enabled**.
(I had to re-edit the SC and click "Allow Volume Expansion : Enabled" again)

I created a PVC, started my pod, stopped the pod. Then I used the "resized" UI to increase the volume size (in Rancher > Cluster x > Project y > Resource > Workload > Volumes > menu button > Resize)
The volume now has: `spec.resources.requests.storage: 20Gi` and `status.capacity.storage: 10Gi` (see yaml below)

But I get the error in Events:

```
ExternalExpanding   Ignoring the PVC: didn't find a plugin capable of expanding the volume; waiting for an external controller to process this PVC.
```

---

The [Volume expansion](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/volume-expansion.html) seems to require an [external-resizer](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/external-resizer.html) Kubernetes CSI [Sidecar Containers](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/sidecar-containers.html).

---

The stotageClass is :

```yaml
#kubectl get storageclass -o yaml testsc 
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: testsc 
parameters:
  datastore: TESTDS
  diskformat: thin
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

PVC

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
    volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: testnode1
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: testpvc
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  storageClassName: testsc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pvc-31d5f008-724a-4da3-b7ab-9bd2c067753e
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  phase: Bound
```

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes in-tree driver seems deprecated in favor of external CSI *"drivers"*. Only few in-tree drivers supports  [volume expansion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims), vsphere/vmware is not listed. furthermore,

> How to resize dynamic volumes once provisioned?
>
> Support for resizing existing dynamic volume is not yet there. Proposal is available [here](https://github.com/gnufied/community/blob/91b41028182a5291b4eccbf88f8065f66b2b7eed/contributors/design-proposals/grow-volume-size.md). vSphere
> Cloud Provider does not support resize of volume. Please track this [issue](https://github.com/vmware/kubernetes/issues/168).

Extending volume is likely to require to use CSI driver instead of Kubernetes' in-tree Vsphere driver.

Rancher now document how to migrate do [vsphere-volume-migration](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-provisioning/rke-clusters/cloud-providers/vsphere/out-of-tree/vsphere-volume-migration/).

P.S. Vmware's Kubernetes Tanzu seems to allow to Expand a Persistent Volume [doc](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/vmware-vsphere-with-tanzu/GUID-90082E1C-DC01-4610-ABA2-6A4E97C18CBC.html)... on VSAN maybe, because the bug [70616](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/70616) states: *PVC resizing is not  yet  supported in the VMware vSphere VMFS file system.*